# Mysql query with many join's takes long time to load

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using this query to get record

```
SELECT *
FROM (`content` as c)
LEFT JOIN `content_assets` AS ca ON `ca`.`contentid` = `c`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `assets` AS a ON `a`.`act_id` = `ca`.`actorid`
INNER JOIN `content_gens` AS cg ON `cg`.`contentid` = `c`.`id`
INNER JOIN `gens` AS g ON `cg`.`genid` = `g`.`gen_id`
LEFT JOIN `live_data` AS l ON `l`.`contentid` = `c`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `live_type` AS lt ON `lt`.`lt_id` = `l`.`live_type`
LEFT JOIN `returned` AS r ON `r`.`content_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `c`.`id` =  '14175'
```

my live_data table is main issue here which is causing this load time, it contains about 200k records and its taking 20-40 seconds to load a page. If I dont join that table everything is fine. I am currently using file based caching to cache result from above query but I would like to know if above query can be optimized more.

Edit: 
My table indexes can be seen here.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 08, 2013 at 11:07 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.16
-- PHP Version: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `database`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `assets`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assets` (
  `act_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
......
  PRIMARY KEY (`act_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8726 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `content`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
.........
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14267 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `content_asset`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content_asset` (
  `contentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `actorid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `content_gener`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content_gener` (
  `contentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `genid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `gens`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gens` (
  `gen_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
......
  PRIMARY KEY (`gen_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=65 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `live_data`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `live_data` (
  `link_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
.....
  PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=214014 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `live_type`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `live_type` (
  `lt_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
....
  PRIMARY KEY (`lt_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `returned`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `returned` (
  `r_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
....
  PRIMARY KEY (`r_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And Explain query result:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: first, the obvious question: are your tables properly indexed?

Comment: Following up @Barranka: are you using InnoDB and foreign keys?

Comment: @Barranka and barbashov Thanks I have updated my question with indexes details and I am using MyISAM.

Comment: @Dshah you're joining on `live_data.contentid` but you have index on `live_data.link_id` only. Create an index on `live_data.contentid`.

Comment: @Dshah and do the same with `content_asset.contentid` and `content_gener.contentid`

Comment: @Dshah oh and move your big tables to InnoDB.

Comment: Views are a possible solution. But are you performing this select statement for every content.id or is it just one per turn (as in your example, 14175)?

Comment: @barbashov WOW after adding indexes page load time decreased to like 70%, and to convert to InnoDb should I use ALTER TABLE `live_data` ENGINE=InnoDB; ? Or any other thing is required as well and please post your comment as answer so I can accept this question. Thanks again and leonardo_assumpcao sorry I dont understand your question.

Comment: Are you always using that where clause, `WHERE c.id = (input)`?

Comment: ah No, just on single item page.

Comment: Hmm, if so, it would easily be thousands of times faster... :\

Comment: In this case, have you thought about creating a view?

Comment: @Dshah, @leonardo_assumpcao means do you have cases when you using query from your question without `WHERE c.id = (input)` clause.

Comment: oh got it, well Yes I am using on some point where I have to display X records with pagination.

Comment: @Dshah then in addition to indexes, InnoDB and foreign keys you should really give views a try :) Also, please accept my answer.

Comment: I agree with barbashov :) Well, if you (maybe) (who knows) want to create a view, add the line `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW content_details AS SELECT ... ... ;`. Once you created it, you'll be able to query for example `SELECT * FROM content_details`, as if it were a normal table. (English is my second language, forgive)

Comment: Ah, you would also have to alias columns with the same name (e.g. the **id** columns) of your select statement.

Comment: More info on views [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-syntax.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will check that :)

Comment: @leonardo_assumpcao I just searched on VIEW and it seems good but I dont understand one thing, Does VIEW save query cache and re run  heavy inner joins as above or is it saved as virtual result and it get updated only when user update it? Thanks

Comment: @Dshah Second option. Views remain *stored* in the database server such as a table, so we can query it every time we need, without having to rewrite it. They're commonly called "virtual tables", formed from normal ("based") tables or even by other views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add indexes on following columns:

- `live_data.contentid`
- `content_asset.contentid`
- `content_gener.contentid`

And convert your big tables to InnoDB using `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB`.

Also it is often a good idea to use [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will check InnoDB :)

Answer (score 1):

If you run `explain [your full query]` in the MySQL console you will see what indexes are used. Depending on the size of each table in the join you want to have indexes on the columns used to connect the tables in the join.